# Kotlin GoogleSignInClient StartActivityForResult returns RESULT_CANCELED

Tags: android-studio, kotlin, google-signin

Could somebody tell me what's wrong with my code? When I press the SignInButton, the Google sign in popup appears, but after selecting the account, the result is always RESULT_CANCELED.

```
class LoginActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    private lateinit var binding: ActivityLoginBinding
    private lateinit var signInButton: SignInButton
    private lateinit var textView: TextView

    private lateinit var signInClient: GoogleSignInClient

    private val launcher = registerForActivityResult(ActivityResultContracts.StartActivityForResult()) { result ->
        if (result.resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
            // never comes here
            textView.text = "Login result " + result.resultCode.toString()
        }
        else
            textView.text = "Login result " + result.resultCode.toString()
    }

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

        binding = ActivityLoginBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
        setContentView(binding.root)
        var gso: GoogleSignInOptions = GoogleSignInOptions.Builder(GoogleSignInOptions.DEFAULT_SIGN_IN)
            .requestEmail()
            .build()
        signInClient = GoogleSignIn.getClient(this, gso)

        textView = binding.textView
        signInButton = binding.signInButton
        signInButton.setOnClickListener {
            launcher.launch(signInClient.signInIntent)
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you try add Web Client OAuth2 in Credential ? And use Web Client ID like a param for signIn, like this:

```
var gso: GoogleSignInOptions = GoogleSignInOptions.Builder(GoogleSignInOptions.DEFAULT_SIGN_IN)
            .requestIdToken("YOUR_WEB_APPLICATION_CLIENT_ID")
            .requestEmail()
            .build()
```

or make sure you declare right dependency in gradle file

Comment: I figured out the problem. I had the wrong SHA-1 fingerprint configured. I don't really understand what's up with the fingerprint, but using keytool gave the wrong one. I managed to get the right one from Gradle's signing report. To me requestIdToken seems unnecessary and it won't help without the right fingerprint.

Thanks for your comment, it helped me find the answer.